# OpenPyXL - How to check if a cells contents go outside the cells boundary size?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Is there a way to check if a cells contents go outside the boundary or size of the cell, and then if that is true apply a word wrap on the cell?  I know how to apply word wrap, but I only wish to do this if the contents are too large for the cell:

```html
wksheet.cell(row=row, column=col).alignment = Alignment(wrap_text=True)
```

Comment: No, this is not possible not least because cell widths are dependent on the viewing application.

Comment: You may be able to guessimate this based on the font and font size used and then wrap if the number of characters in the cell is >= x, if the cell has values. If its a function then you cannot determine the characters.